# Best practice for handling public and internal IDs in REST APIs using UUID and slug columns in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, url, routes

I have a table that contains a classic auto-incrementing ID and the name of the business. To avoid exposing the business ID to the client, I want to use a UUID. So far, so good. The only thing is that for calling it from the URL, it may be better to have a more user-friendly format like "api/businesses/my-business" instead of "api/businesses/10b940f2-5f8c-42ac-9c35-b6d0de45995b". Therefore, if I add a "slug" column to the table to use for GET requests, while using the UUID for data updates, would this be considered a best practice?

In my case, I need to create a record in a quotes table, and therefore the PATCH will be:

```
PATCH /api/quotes/4dc93692-0ad9-4131-94fe-b4afec88d037

{
    "business_uuid": "10b940f2-5f8c-42ac-9c35-b6d0de45995b",
    "object": "My quote object",
    "another_column": "Hello",
}
```

Comment: This is fine so long as you're able to ensure the slugs are unique to each record. Consider if these slugs should also be able to be updated (eg if your slugs is based onthe business name, and that name changes, can this be changed and still kept unique, bearing in mind anywhere else that has stored this slug is now invalid)

Comment: Yes, I understand this. The slug must be well managed in the code. Otherwise, should I not include the slug and use the UUID directly in the URL for the GET request? Although in this way, I would lose the SEO (even though it's not an e-commerce, so I wouldn't need it 100%)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database table structure contains `id`, `uuid`, `slug`, consider following:

1. Use `id` internally within backend only.
2. Use `uuid` when processing resources with REST API (CRUD).
3. Use `slug` when you want to process resources somewhere where its more easier for human to read/identify/understand data. Don't forget that `slug` must be unique. But for basic CRUD operations between services I would still recommend to keep using `uuid`.

I would also recommend to checkout Laravel docs regarding [Laravel Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources) which can help you to prepare data for API, and [slugify helper](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-fluent-str-slug) function to process one of your data fields.